# SQL Query to group multiple items with the same index into the same row

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

So I have three tables containing data about users and their departments, and I need to create a query that organizes the data between them. The first table contains the users' names and their IDs, and looks like this:

```
user_name   user_id
-----------------------
bob         1
chuck       2
bill        3
```

The next table indexes the users with their department IDs, like this:

```
user_id     department_id
-----------------------------
1           x
1           y
2           x
3           z
2           z
2           y
```

and the last table lists the department names according to their IDs:

```
department_id   department_name
-------------------------------
x               research
y               development
z               advertising
```

How do I write a query that lists all the users along with each department they are in? It should look something like this:

```
user_name   user_id     department_1    department_2    department_3
----------------------------------------------------------------------------
bob         1           research        development
chuck       2           research        development     advertising
bill        3           advertising
```

I have tried many different methods and I can't find anything that gives me this result. My output currently lists duplicate users if they have more than one department, like this:

```
user_name   user_id     department_1    department_2    department_3
----------------------------------------------------------------------------
bob         1           research        research        research
bob         1           development     development     development
chuck       2           research        research        research
chuck       2           development     development     development
chuck       3           advertising     advertising     advertising
bill        3           advertising     advertising     advertising
```

Current code:

```
WITH DATA AS
(
SELECT 
Users.user_name AS Name,
Users.user_id AS Id,
Departments.department_name AS Department1,
Departments.department_name AS Department2,
Departments.department_name AS Department3
FROM Users
    JOIN Department_Index ON Users.user_id = Department_Index.user_id
    JOIN Departments ON Departments.department_id = Department_Index.department_id
WHERE Departments.department_id = Department_Index.department_id
)

SELECT
Name,Id,Department1,Department2,Department3
FROM DATA
```

I also tried something like this

```
WITH DATA AS
(
SELECT 
Users.user_name AS Name,
Users.user_id AS Id,
( SELECT Departments.department_name
  FROM Departments
     JOIN Department_Index ON Department_Index.user_id = Users.user_id
  WHERE Departments.department_name = Department_Index.department_name
) AS Departments
FROM Users
)

SELECT
Name,Id,Departments[0],Departments[1],Departments[2]
FROM DATA
```

But that didn't work either.

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Can you show us what you've done so far? Can you have more than 3 departments?

Comment: [Using PIVOT and UNPIVOT](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177410(v=sql.105).aspx)

Comment: sure would be nice to know what your table names are... I guess we can guess.

Comment: @MegaTron It is possible they could be in more than 3 departments, but the query only needs to return up to 3. Edited my post with my code and table names.

Comment: ooooh plural name tables. Convention has it the tables would be named "user" and "department".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wrote this before you told us the table names.

The key is to use the row_number() windowing function to order the department names and then join back to this CTE 3 times.

```
with ud_numbered as
(
   select u.user_id, ud.department_id, d.department_name
       row_number() over (partition by u.user_id order by ud.department_id asc) as dept_no
   from user_table u
   left join user_departement ud on u.user_id = ud1.user_id
   left join department d on ud.department_id = d.department_id
)
select u.user_id, u.user_name, n1.department_name as department_1,
                               n2.department_name as department_2, 
                               n3.department_name as department_3
from user_table u
left join ud_numbered n1 on u.user_id = n1.user_id and n1.dept_no = 1
left join ud_numbered n2 on u.user_id = n2.user_id and n2.dept_no = 2
left join ud_numbered n3 on u.user_id = n3.user_id and n3.dept_no = 3
```

Answer (score 0):

I personally would approach this with [`ROW_NUMBER()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186734.aspx) and [`PIVOT`](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177410(v=sql.105).aspx). `ROW_NUMBER()` will give each department a unique identifier per person, starting at 1, then you can use this identifier to pivot on. The aggregate function used, in this case `MAX` is arbitrary since, as stated the identifier is unique anyway, so you are taking the `MAX` of a single value:

```
WITH UserData AS
(   SELECT  u.[user_id], 
            u.[user_name],
            d.department_name,
            RowNumber = ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY u.[user_id] ORDER BY d.department_id)
    FROM    Users AS u
            INNER JOIN Department_Index AS di
                ON di.user_id = u.user_id
            INNER JOIN Departments AS d
                ON d.department_id = di.department_id
)
SELECT  pvt.[user_id],
        pvt.[user_name],
        Department1 = pvt.[1],
        Department2 = pvt.[2],
        Department3 = pvt.[3]
FROM    Data AS d
        PIVOT 
        (   MAX(department_name)
            FOR RowNumber IN ([1], [2], [3])
        ) AS pvt;
```